# 'Disappear in' vs 'disappear from'

Tags: prepositions

I came across this sentence on an ESL teaching website while preparing for my English Corner:

> "What holidays have disappeared **in** your country?"

Shouldn't it be "disappeared **from**"? I was quite certain that "from" was the correct preposition in this case, but it seems that Google doesn't support me on this. I'm a little confused now...

Comment: Turn the sentence around: **In your country, what holidays have disappeared?** **From your country, what holidays have disappeared?** Which do you prefer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

The following is correct, assuming a neutral tone:

> "What holidays have disappeared in your country?"

### Explanation

It's true that `disappear` does not need a preposition to function, as both @J.R.♦ and @Jawel have already stated in this thread, but **disappeared from** creates a nuance that something or someone that was there but now isn't, and its absence creates an often weird or eerie feeling, and to rectify this feeling, he/she/it should be back where he/she/it is. Other prepositions don't create this nuance.

### Examples

> The notebook disappeared from my desk.

(The notebook was on my desk, and now it's not. But it should be. How weird.)

> The notebook on my desk disappeared.

(The notebook was on my desk, and now it's not. Oh, well.)

> What holidays have disappeared from your country?

What holidays were there, and now aren't (but should be reinstated because you're not used to them being gone)?

> What holidays have disappeared in your country?

As @Ronald Sole indicated, "In your country, what holidays have disappeared?"

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that you are wrong, but indeed, you are..

The linking verbs "*disappear*" and "*appear*" don't need any proposition to function.

> - Why did you **disappear** at the party yesterday?
> - Oh, my mother called me and mentioned some important things causing me to go home.

Answer (score 0):

I think both versions are fine.

As you point out, "disappear from" is idiomatic speech:

> Why has so much money disappeared from my bank account?
>   The turtles disappeared from the beach.

However, many other prepositions can also follow *disappear*:

> The moon disappeared behind the cloud.
>   She disappeared into a thick fog.
>   The spider disappeared under the bed as soon as I turned on the light.

And, of course, you don't need any preposition at all:

> After Belgium scored two quick goals, Germany's two-goal lead had quickly disappeared.

So, as other answers and comments have indicated, try parsing your sentence differently:

> INSTEAD OF: [What holidays] [have disappeared in] [your country]?
>   THINK OF IT AS: [What holidays] [have disappeared] [in your country]?

But:

> What holidays have disappeared from your country?

would be fine, too.